# Vim Macro which accepts user input

Tags: vim, user-input, interactive, vim-macros

Lets say I have the following text file

```
name: John Doe
description: My name is John Doe and I'm really good at vim!
name: John Doe
description: My name is John Doe and I'm really good at vim!
name: John Doe
description: My name is John Doe and I'm really good at vim!
name: John Doe
description: My name is John Doe and I'm really good at vim!
```

Is there a way to record a macro that does the following:

Starting at the first `John`:

1. `cw` but allow the user who runs the macro to give input here
2. `js<is>w` sneak the word after is
3. `.` replace John with the given input
4. Repeat

Ideally I would like to enter the following keystrokes on the first line:

`@qJane`

and have:

```
name: Jane Doe
description: My name is Jane Doe and I'm really good at vim!
```

`@qJim`

```
name: Jim Doe
description: My name is Jim Doe and I'm really good at vim!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to take user input is to use the [`input()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#input%28%29) function, which lets you prompt for a name and use it in expressions.

Unfortunately, you can't really use it from a macro, since a macro would record your answer to the prompt as well (and replaying one you build would have a similar issue.)

You can use it from a function and bind that function to a key map though:

```
function! ChangeName()
  let newname = input('Name? ')
  return '0/\<John\>'."\<cr>cw".newname."\<esc>n."
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <leader>cn ChangeName()
```

You can then type `\cn`, which will prompt you for a new name. Once you type the new name and press ENTER, it will replace the first two occurrences of `John` with the new name.

The function returns the expansion of the mapping, using `<expr>` in the map command to have it use the return value of the function. (Having the function issue a `:normal!` command with an `:execute` would also be a possible approach.)

You mentioned pressing `@qJim` or `@qJane`, where there's not a prompt and the new name "feels" like part of the command. It's possible to get closer to something like that by using [`getchar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29) in a loop from the function behind your mapping. You still need to decide on how to terminate the name, will you take an ENTER at the end? Will you use timing to decide when the command is over (need to type it quickly?) You might also need to handle backspace and cancelling the command if you use `getchar()`. Using `input()` is certainly easier, and might be enough depending on your particular use case.

Comment: I like this, especially the `getchar()` part

Comment: `getchar()` can be tricky... But if you're interested in that, take a look at the [first few lines of vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/plugin/surround.vim) for some ideas on that. The vim-surround plug-in does something similar to get surround characters and html tags, which is perhaps close to what you want.

Comment: What is the exclamation mark after `function` for?

Comment: @MartínNieva See `:help :function`. (In general, Vim has a very rich help system, always use that first, as in most cases it can answer your questions directly.)

Answer (score 2):

Although  `q`  is often  used  with  the term  *macro*,  its
purpose  is  to  simply  record and  repeat  a  sequence  of
characters. Repeating being key here  — if your intention is
not to repeat the same  exact sequence, then `q` is probably
not the ideal solution.

You should be able to achieve this easily with a map instead
(note that `:h macro` will point you to `:map`). You can use
`:execute` to  build a  command which substitutes  the first
occurrences of *John* in the current line and the line after
with whatever  `input()` returns. The latter  is responsible
for prompting the user.

Here's a small example that implements this mapped to `,n`:

```
:nnoremap ,n :exe ',+s/John/' . input('Name: ')<CR>
```

If you don't  know the name to be replaced,  you can ask for
that too:

```
:nnoremap ,n :exe ',+s/' . input('Old name: ') . '/' . input('New name: ')<CR>
```

Or use  a regex which  captures the first word  after "name"
ignoring ":" or "is":

```
:nnoremap ,n :exe ',+s/\vname(: \| is )+\zs\w+/' . input('New name: ')<CR>
```

Comment: While this is certainly a solution, its not quite as general as I would like. It seems there no way to accept input from a macro unfortunately. With this solution (unless I'm mistaken) I would have to map a new command and replace `,+s/John/` with the name I want to replace

Comment: @DanielCooke There is a way to accept input in a macro, which is demonstrated above. Note the distinction between macro and repeated keystrokes done by recorded sequenced with `q`. As for replacing John with the name you want, you mean manually? Of course not. Did you try executing the solution I posted? Type in the solution and then you can replace your names with `,nJoe`, `,nJane`, etc.

Comment: Yes, and what im saying is - this command will not work for names that aren't John. 
What if I want to replace `Chris` with `Dan` - you have hardcoded in the string `,+s/John/` into the command. So as I said previously - I would have to change this hardcoded string everytime I want to change a new name

Comment: @DanielCooke Well, you didn't mentioned that in your original question but I'll update my answer with a couple solutions.

Comment: And just to further clarify, when you `:map` you are not creating a command, you're creating a macro. A command is created with `:command!`. A sequence of repeated keystrokes can be recorded with `q`.

Comment: @siidyll thanks for the update! Is it possible to use `cw` in this macro? If so that would be perfect.